# Adding inputs to bottom of table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a main sheet to input data and a button that takes that data and puts it into a table.

When I input data into the table, it leaves a blank row. How can I insert data into the table without this issue?

```
'================================================================
'Button on MASTER sheet
'Functions: inputs new digsafe data into LIST sheet
'================================================================
Sub add_to_list()
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet: Set wsMaster = Worksheets("MASTER")
Dim wsList As Worksheet: Set wsList = Worksheets("LIST")
Dim table_list_object As ListObject: Set table_list_object = 
wsList.ListObjects("Table1")
Dim table_object_row As ListRow: Set table_object_row = 
table_list_object.ListRows.Add
Dim digsafe As Long
Dim workType As String, crossStreet As String, address As String
Dim dateTime As Date

digsafe = wsMaster.Range("C5").Value                'Stores values inputted by user
dateTime = wsMaster.Range("C6").Value
workType = wsMaster.Range("C7").Value
crossStreet = wsMaster.Range("C8").Value
address = wsMaster.Range("C9").Value

wsList.Activate
table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = digsafe        'Inputs data at end of the table (Table1)
table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = dateTime
table_object_row.Range(1, 3).Value = workType
table_object_row.Range(1, 4).Value = crossStreet
table_object_row.Range(1, 5).Value = address

For Each Cell In wsMaster.Range("C5:C9")            'Clears data from DS Input after entered
    Cell.Value = ""
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that instead of that `For Each` loop in the end you can just reset the values with only one command `wsMaster.Range("C5:C9").Value = vbNullString`

Comment: Can you add screenshots of your sample data?

Comment: Try Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add (Position:=LastRow, AlwaysInsert:=True/False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's code did not add an empty row for me.  I rewrote the code to make sure that there is valid input data and to remove any empty rows in the table.

```
Sub add_to_list()
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
    Set Source = Worksheets("MASTER").Range("C6").Resize(5)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Source) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set Target = Worksheets("LIST").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add.Range(1, 1).Resize(1, 5)
    Target.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Source.Value)
    Source.ClearContents
    DeleteEmptyRowsFromList
End Sub

Sub DeleteEmptyRowsFromList()
    Dim r As Long
    With Worksheets("LIST").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
        For r = .Rows.count To 1 Step -1
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(r)) = 0 Then .Rows(r).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The .ListRow object has a Range property. So if you set the values to this range property, it will add it too the table in the new row, without having to delete rows or so:

```
Sub tt()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim t_row As ListRow
Dim v
For Each tbl In SheetAdminLog.ListObjects
    Debug.Print tbl.ListRows.Count

    v = Range("A1:N1").Value
    Set t_row = tbl.ListRows.Add
    Debug.Print t_row.Range.Address
    t_row.Range.Value = v
Next
End Sub
```